# Using javascript in Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf, inline

```
<script  th:inline="javascript">

            /*<![CDATA[*/
                
                var msg = [[${msg}]];
                
            /*]]*/
             
</script>
```

The red line appears on the first curly brace and it says ' "," is expected. '
What is the problem? How should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the correct way to do [natural templates w/JavaScript](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#javascript-natural-templates), it should look like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  var msg = /*[[${msg}]]*/ "";
</script>
```